# Did a Pfizer subcontractor compromise the integrity of some data in Pfizer's Covid vaccine trial?

Tags: covid-19, vaccines

According to [Paul D Thacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_D._Thacker) in [this article](https://www.bmj.com/content/375/bmj.n2635) published in [the BMJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_BMJ), a whistleblower working for a subcontractor in Texas (Ventavia Research Group) reported a number of problems, and was then immediately fired after informing the FDA.

> She then listed a dozen concerns she had witnessed, including:
>
> Participants placed in a hallway after injection and not being monitored by clinical staff
>
> Lack of timely follow-up of patients who experienced adverse events
>
> Protocol deviations not being reported
>
> Vaccines not being stored at proper temperatures
>
> Mislabelled laboratory specimens, and
>
> Targeting of Ventavia staff for reporting these types of problems.

Are these serious problems for a clinical trial site, and do they mean that the results of the Pfizer clinical trial as a whole are questionable?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136186/discussion-on-question-by-graviton-did-a-pfizer-subcontractor-compromise-the-int).